# Landing Download Page for PHP

Tags: php, download

I have a salesforce form embedded [here](http://www.kextil.com/register.php). What this form does is to take the user input data from my site to salesforce.com and after saving the data there it comes back to my site through a return url passed into the form.

Now, the page where it should return has a file download function. The file downloads alright but the url in the browser is where the form is submitted. I want the browser to navigate to my site after the form has been submitted and download the file while showing a message at the same time. Currently only file downloads and that too from a blank page.

Now the headers i'm passing from the download/thankyou page are :

```
        header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
```

And i flush the buffer after the that :

```
    ob_clean(); flush(); 
    exit($data);
```

Please have a go at the form if you want and comment if the info is not sufficient. The site is still in debug mode. Also, guide me as to what i should do to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final URL that the browser lands on will either be a document with a MIME type that the browser can understand (e.g. `text/html`) or it won't. If it is, the browser will display it and display the corresponding URL in the address bar. If it isn't (e.g. `application/exe`) it will download it and leave the URL as it was.

If you want to display a message while you're downloading, you'll have to serve back an HTML page (with MIME type `text/html`) that says "Your download will start shortly" and then kick off the download with JavaScript, something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Downloading your file</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Downloading your file</h1>
    <p>Your download will begin shortly</p>

    <script>
        window.setTimeout(
            function() {
                window.location.href = "/mydownload.exe";
            },
            3000 // start download after 3 seconds
        );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok ... i am gonna try this... seems to be valid ... dont know why didnt i come up with this ....

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have the "return" page from saleforce.com to be a regular php file, say, *thankyou.php*, which just displays HTML to the end user.  In the HTML/JS you would also redirect to the download. Something like this:

```
echo "Thank you.  Your file download will start shortly</h2>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = '$filename'</script>";
```

And then in a separate *download.php* put the code you showed above.

Note that I'm only showing you the idea.  Normally, you would want to (a) separate HTML and JS; and (b) check that you really did come form the correct salesforce.com page and got the correct return results.  Finally, you may want to put in a delay, so that the download would start after 5-10 seconds after the page is displayed.  Check the `setTimeout` javascript function.